# Formating API data returns "undefined" in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So what im trying to do is format the data since API gives A LOT of stuff i have no use for, but in console its always returning as "undefined" or "null" in this case

im importing and calling the fetch API inside another component which is at the bottom

This is unformated data bellow

[image]

```
export async function getCurrentData() {
    try {
        const apiData = await requestAPI("current", { city: "london,UK", })
        .then(data => currentDataFormat(data))
        return apiData
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err)
        return null
    }
}


function currentDataFormat(data) {
    const {
        weather: { icon, description },
        city_name, country_code, datetime, lat, lon, sunrise, sunset, temp, wind_spd
    } = data.current.data[0]

    return {icon, description, city_name, country_code, datetime, lat, lon, sunrise, sunset, temp, wind_spd}
}

function requestAPI(infoType, searchParams) {
    const url = new URL(API_URL + infoType)
    url.search = new URLSearchParams({ ...searchParams, key: API_KEY })

    return fetch(url)

        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data)
        .catch(err => err)
}
```

````
    const [data, setData] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    async function getData() {
        try {
            const hourlyData = await getHourlyData()
            const dailyData = await getDailyData()
            const currentWeatherData = await getCurrentData()
            setData({ hourly: hourlyData, daily: dailyData, current: currentWeatherData })
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return null
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you provide a [mre], including how you call the function and access the result?

Comment: Mixing `async`/`await` coding with `.then()` callbacks is always a red flag for me. It's very easy to get confused about what's returning what to where.

Comment: @Unmitigated when i use ```data``` insted of ```currentDataFormat(data)``` inside ```getCurrentData()``` it works fine i get API call like the one in the picture, but i cant format it for some reason

Comment: @Pointy well im about  2-3 months into learning to code properly so i guess spaghetti code like this is expected 

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.then()` if you're using `await`.

```js
export async function getCurrentData() {
    try {
        const data = await requestAPI("current", { city: "london,UK" });
        const apiData = currentDataFormat(data);
        return apiData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution was `data.data[0]` instead of `data.current.data[0]`

Im not 100% sure but i think i was trying to access `current Data` not knowing it was already accessed inside `getCurrentData()`

```js
function currentDataFormat(data) {
    const {
        weather: { icon, description },
        city_name, country_code, datetime, lat, lon, sunrise, sunset, temp, wind_spd
    } = data.data[0]

    return {icon, description, city_name, country_code, datetime, lat, lon, sunrise, sunset, temp, wind_spd}
}
```